# What would be a better terminology to use for non technical users, Site Parameters or Site Variables?

Tags: language

We have a system that allows you to configure analytics for your website and include goals that you would like to track, goals can be defined by page visits or image pixels fired for instance, in case of image pixel fired, we centralize the definitions in one place and allow later the use to choose which pixel\event fired he would like to use for report calculations.

To these pixel\events we call them site variables\parameters.
We would like to develop a general variables functionality in our system, that will allow then to do operations with the variables.

Currently we are debating internally what would be a better terminology to use, Site Parameters or Site Variables for end, not very technical, users. What do you think?

Comment: Where are you using this? What does the system do? Provide any additional information you can.

Comment: If your end users aren't very technical, why are you exposing variables to them in the first place?

Comment: Its a system that allows you to configure you analytics for your website and include goals that you would like to track, goals can be defined by page visits or image pixels fired for instance, in case of image pixel fired, we centralize the definitions in one place and allow later the use to choose which pixel\event fired he would like to use for report calculations. These pixel\events we call them site variables\parameters. –

Comment: How did you decide to limit it to "site parameters" or "site variables"?  Why not "things to measure" or "analysis options"?  As it stands, this question is far too narrow to be useful.

Comment: Well, because all these things are something that the site owner will need to pass to us for us to use in the system, additional things are going to be measured anyway, without him passing anything to us (like referring site for instance). In Google analytics a similar thing is named Goals, but thats because its used only for Goal definition, where is we allow to define automatic processes and rules based on these parameters, as well as additional reports...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible to give a good answer to this question without more context. When you say...

> We would like to develop a general variables functionality in our system, that will allow then to do operations with the variables.

... it sounds like something a non-technical user would have a hard time understanding, regardless of the terminology you chose.

I'm hopeful there is an answer, but it really depends on the context. THe right vocabulary would be different if the system is for configuring a rental car vs configuring a menu for a dinner party.

Good luck!

Comment: I've updated the original question...